# Parse dashboard error

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

I successfully installed parse dashboard using the commands on the github repo. 
When I try to run it from the command line I get the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-dashboard/Parse-Dashboard/index.js:10
const path = require('path');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-dashboard/bin/parse-dashboard:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Any one have any idea of what is going on here and how I can fix it?

Comment: It turns out that my node version is out of date. I currently have version `0.12.71`. Maybe an update will fix the problem. Will let you know soon.

Comment: Updating the node version solved the issue.